# get all params inside brackets in string on javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this string variable with some numbers inside brackets:

```
var num = '[3][8]1';
```

I want to get the bracketed numbers ('3' and '8' in this case) pushed into a new array.

This is what I have tried:

```
var searchFill = num.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
console.log(searchFill[1]);
```

But this only displays the first element matched inside brackets. How can I get all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `g` as global for regex:

```js
var num = '[3][8]1';
var searchFill = num.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
console.log(searchFill);
```

Why [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) should be used:

> The value of global is a Boolean and true if the "g" flag was used; otherwise, false. The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string. A regular expression defined as both global ("g") and sticky ("y") will ignore the global flag and perform sticky matches.

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
var num = '[3][8]1';
var searchFill = num.match(/\[(.*?)[0-9]\]/g);
console.log(searchFill);
```

```js
var num = '[3][8]1';
var searchFill = num.match(/\[(.*?)[0-9]\]/g);
console.log(searchFill);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `g` at the end of your RegExp like:
`/\[(.*?)\]/g`. The `g` means the Expression will be searched globally in the whole String. 
Or, if you prefer, add a `*` like `/\[(.*?)*\]/`, which means, that the selection-group may appear 0-n times instead of exactly one time like in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted you will have to use the `g` global flag. But I also suspect that you want just the number in the brackets and not the brackets themselves. For that you may want to use [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) rather than match as match will discard the capture groups.

```js
var num = '[3][8]1'
var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g
var searchFill = [] 
var match;
while(match = regex.exec(num)){
  searchFill.push(match[1])
}

console.log(searchFill)
```